# how to fetch selected entire row data using php without Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, api

In my program, one part is fetching data from api and display in the table.
I used php for this process.now i want to fetch the selected row value using php.I didn't stored this data in Mysql.

```
$url = //my api
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$characters = json_decode($data); 
foreach ($characters as $character) {
     //print all data in table 
}
```

My table is:
[My Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf25r.png)

if i select first row then i want get

Product name :Bud Ice 22oz NR, Each
NewPrice:1.29
BarocdeID: 02885324 ... (entire row value)

So what is the way to get selected row value using php?

Comment: Can you provide more details (data sample, expected result, etc.)?

Comment: I attached my table. if i select first row i want get Product name :Bud Ice 22oz NR, Each  Price:1.29 BarocdeID: 02885324

Answer (score 1):

Let me just be sure I understand - you're getting the data from an API, then printing it straight away, you don't have the data stored locally, and when someone selects a row, you'd like to get the data from that row?

I'd do that in Javascript. You *could* do it in PHP by also printing the values to hidden input fields, wrapping it all in a form and reading the data when submitted, but that way is just worse in every way. I'd much recommend you use Javascript to read the fields when selected, then send them to PHP via AJAX.

Comment: i think there is no way to convert javascript to php.Because it is scripting to backend conversion.I need it in PHP

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't really make sense to me. As I understand it, you just want to send the data. You can use any format for that, but JSON would be the obvious one as both Javascript and PHP can easily read and write it.
Why do you want to convert it to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the response make an array and store all the data in it.

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
            'productName'=>'Bud ice 123',
            'uomName'=>'Each',
            'newPrice'=>1.29
        ),
    1 => array(
            'productName'=>'Bud ice3321',
            'uomName'=>'Each',
            'newPrice'=>1.29
        )
);
```

You have to store the response in array somewhat like this first.

Then while printing in the table as you have mentioned; in the value attribute provide a the key of array accordingly.

By the key of array while storing api response you can take the whole row data.

Comment: i have more than 200 records in that API and each 30sec the page will automatically refresh..So i think this one is not possible.